# Using the assignment operator in a while loop condition in C

Tags: c, while-loop, variable-assignment

The question is:

Rewrite the following C code in a more readable style:

```
while (*dst++ = *src++);
```

I want to check that I am understanding this line correctly. By assigning *src to *dst, it is checking if *dst (and, by extension, *src) is a non-zero (or zero) value. If non-zero, the `while` body is executed, otherwise it is skipped.

My answer, based on the above understanding:

```
*dst = *src;
while (*dst) {
   [do stuff]
   *dst++;
   *src++;
   *dst = *src;
}
```

I realize that the position of the post-increment for both variables is important for a real program, but I don't think it matters here.

Comment: No, the logic is not exactly correct. The pointers are always incremented at least once. What is "do stuff"? The original loop has no body. If you add one, then the placement of "stuff" is incorrect. Also `*x++;` on its own has a useless `*`.

Comment: the thing you missed is that your original while loop is *copying* src to dst (till it hit null terminator), it is not simply a different syntax for a for loop.

Comment: I'd use `while ((*dst++ = *src++) != '\0') ;` with the semicolon on the next line on its own.  It makes explicit that the result of the assignment is compared with zero (which is what the compiler has to do anyway — it doesn't add anything to the object code).

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is exactly what is being done (`char`s are copied along with null terminator) on the one-line code. But in your code

```
*dst++;
*src++;
```

can be replaced by

```
dst++;
src++;
```

You have **dereferenced it unnecessarily**.

To explain a bit further the value assigned is the value of the assignment expression which is being checked in the while condition which when turns out to be `\0` terminates the loop but the `\0` is copied in the `dst` also.

The implementation you wrote also will do one check and one assignment even if it is empty string just like the original one.

And yes in your case, the post increment or pre increment doesn't matter but in original implementation ***it does***.

By the last line I meant,`++dst;++src;`*will be **same** as* `dst++;src++;` in ***your*** case.

But in original implementation if you have used

```
*++dst = *++src
```

This would be **wrong and meaningless** for the purpose of copying. Think of the case when it is empty string. You will access array index out of bound.

---

> ```
> while(*dst++ = *src++);
> ```

This is **readable** - in fact for the second code you wrote I have to think twice of the edge cases - here it is clean simple logic. Less code Less confusion. *Readability doesn't mean  more code - it is the clean code which is more readable.*

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, the original loop is a common C idiom for copying a zero-terminated string. Any C programmer should recognize it at a glance. So in that sense it it already quite readable.

The revised version is harder to understand, with the repeated assignment outside and inside the loop.

If you want to write it out step by step in the most detailed manner possible, while also keeping exactly the same behavior as the original, I suggest this, assuming that `src` and `dst` are `char*` pointers.

```
// This extra pair of curly braces keeps the `char c` local to this code
{
    char c;  // Change this if the type is different
    do {
        c = *src;
        *dst = c;
        src = src + 1;
        dst = dst + 1;
    } while( c );
}
```

BTW one problem with the original is that many modern C compilers will issue a warning on the assignment, the idea being that it may be a typo for an intended `==` comparison. You can usually suppress this warning with an extra set of parentheses:

```
while(( *dst++ = *src++ )) ;
```

Comment: Hmm, I seem to remember that `char c` wouldn't be in scope for the `while ( c )`.

Comment: Oh, good catch, thanks. I updated it to fix that. Of course that also meant I had to add another pair of curly braces to keep the variable `c` local to this bit of code. Whew!

Answer (score 1):

```
   *dst++;
   *src++;
```

is same as

```
   *dst; <<dereferencing for no use. 
    dst++;  
   *src; <<dereferencing for no use.
    src++;
```

Answer (score 1):

> By assigning *src to *dst, it is checking if *dst (and, by extension,
>   *src) is a non-zero (or zero) value. If non-zero, the while body is executed, otherwise it is skipped.

That's correct as far as it goes, but as far as the *purpose* of such code goes, it misses the point.  A high-level description of the function of the code would be: copy successive elements of the array pointed into by `src` to successive elements of the array pointed into by `dst` until an element with value 0 has been copied.  In particular, if `src` and `dst` are pointers to `char` then this is a possible implementation of the `strcpy()` function.

But your characterization does not describe *all* the effects of the code, which include incrementing the `src` and `dst` pointers to one position past the last element copied.  Your version does not match this.  Moreover, your version is a bit odd in how it performs the pointer increments, in that after it performs the increments, it pointlessly dereferences the new pointer values and ignores the results.  *That's* not good style.

There are a lot of alternatives that I would consider more readable, but your instructor may be looking for some particular characteristics.  I expect first of all that they would want a version that does not use an assignment expression in boolean context.  I imagine that they would also want to see the pointer dereferences and pointer increments performed in separate expressions.  Here's a version that has those characteristics, that produces all the side effects of the original code, and that minimizes code duplication:

```
do {
    *dst = *src;
    dst++;
    src++;
} while (*(src - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of what the loop does is correct, but not your understanding of the post-increment, the post-increment has higher precedence than the *, so in the original while loop the post-increment increments the pointers (returning the original values), then dereferences those pointers assigning original *src to original *dest.

I suggest doing it as a for loop (although the original is already highly idiomatic):

```
for( ; *dst = *src; ++dst, ++src)
{ }
```

Comment: I agree that that's better, inasmuch as it separates the pointer increment operations from the dereferences and assignment.  But it still uses the value of the assignment expression in boolean context, which I'd argue is an even bigger readability problem.